# htaccess not working in iis

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis

friends. I'm creating an .htaccess file with rewrite rules. It's working fine in localhost, but on the live, server it's not working. My hosting uses a Window server.

I wrote this Rule in my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: IIS doesn't do .htaccess files. They are an Apache thing. On URL rewriting on IIS, see e.g. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 4):

By default, IIS does not support .httacces and Apache mode_rewrite rules. To achieve this, you will have to install Helicon Ape addon along with IIS. Helicon Ape offers support for the Apache .htaccess and .htpasswd configuration files in Microsoft IIS.

With Helicon Ape you can use modules, like mod_rewrite, mod_proxy, mod_auth, mod_gzip, mod_headers, mod_cache, mod_expires, mod_replace and others under single IIS addon. Single website license for Helicon Ape will cost you $47 one time.

If you want to have free alternative, you can go with native IIS URL Rewrite Module. [Microsoft URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) offers similar functionality like Apache mod_rewrite module with the help of web.config file. You can simply install this module and import your .httacces rules to IIS web server. This module also lets you convert the existing Apache mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL rewrite rules and store them to web.config automatically. For more information, refer to following tutorial.

https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2415/How-to-Enable-modrewrite-on-IIS-Web-Server.html